# How do I apply assumptions to a module (or any CompoundExpression)?

Tags: assumptions

Edit: I am looking for a way to apply assumptions to all expressions contained in a compound expression.
For example,

```
f[x_] := CompoundExpression[Clear[n], If[x > 0, n = 1, n = 2], 
   Array[#1 &, n]];
```

Output of this function is supposed to be an array of length either 1 or 2, and that is exactly what happens, when a numeric value is passed to the function.

Now I want to do the same, but without assigning a numeric value to x. I would use assumption, that x>0, and try to execute the function. I get output:

```
 Array[#1 &, n]
```

instead of array {1}, that I would expect. I have tried the following:

```
Refine[f[x],{x>0}]
Assuming[x>0,Refine[f[x]]]
```

and even

```
$Assumptions=x>0
Refine[f[x]]
```

But with no success.

Original text:
I am trying to write a function, which performs several calculations, say:

```
f[a_, b_] := Module[{x},
   (*some irrelevant code omitted*)
   Print[If[a > b, "a", "b"]];
   (*more code omitted*)
   If[a>b,a,b]];
```

And everything runs smoothly if the two variables (a,b) are assigned a numerical value:

```
f[1,2]
```

gives output

```
b
2
```

Now I want to use this function in a symbolic calculation. 
And this is where my problem appears. 
I am trying to apply assumptions to help comparing the two values:

```
Clear[a, b];
Refine[f[a, b], {a > b}]
```

And I would expect to get output:

```
a
a
```

, but what I get instead is:

```
If[a>b,a,b]
a
```

My question is: how do I apply the assumptions to that function properly?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: `Refine` is applied to the return value of `f[a,b]`.  The `Print` statement has already happened at that point.  Do you want a function that will go through the statements in the definition of `f` and refine each one?  And then execute the refined code?  Or ignore all the code except the `Print` statement and the return value?

Comment: Hi, Michael! Yes, I am looking for a function that goes through the definition of my function and refines each statement.

Answer (score 2):

You could replace all expressions in the compound expression by expressions refined by assumed predicates:

```
SetAttributes[refine,HoldFirst];
refine[expr_,pred_]:=Replace[Unevaluated@expr,x_:>Refine[x,pred],1]
refine[CompoundExpression[Clear[n],If[x>0,n=1,n=2],Array[#1&,n]],x>0]
```

This only replaces expressions at the 1st level inside `CompoundExpression`, so it will not do what you want with `Print[If[a > b, "a", "b"]]`. For that, you would need the replacement to give `Print[Refine[If[a > b, "a", "b"], a>b]]`, which would require replacing up to the 2nd level.

I tried modifying `refine` to do so, but immediately ran into problems with unwanted replacements, e.g. `Clear[n]` being replaced by `Clear[Refine[n, x>0]]`. You might think to use something like `RuleCondition` to evaluate `Refine` wherever it's used, but then the expression being refined will also be evaluated, e.g. if `n=1`, `Clear[Evaluate@Refine[n, x>0]]` becomes `Clear[1]`.

Lacking a better solution, I have restricted replacements to only expressions containing symbols in the predicates:

```
refine[expr_,pred_]:=Replace[Unevaluated@expr,x_/;
                     MemberQ[Unevaluated@x,Alternatives@@Cases[pred,_Symbol,Infinity],Infinity]:>
                     Refine[x,pred],Infinity]
```

which works on expressions at any level (except the 0th). This works with the `CompoundExpression` example, and also in the module from the original:

```
Module[{x},refine[Print[If[a>b,"a","b"]];If[a>b,a,b],a>b]]
```

However I can't vouch for its robustness in general, because even among only expressions containing symbols in the predicates, some replacements may cause problems.